# Visnetwork pie chart nodes

Tags: graph, pie-chart, visnetwork

How could I replace the vertex shape in a visnetwork rendered graph with pie charts? I know igraph can make this through the plot function and the vertex shape pie http://igraph.org/r/doc/vertex.shape.pie.html. What would be the equivalent in visnetwork?

Comment: I need this as well

Comment: Same here, upvoted

Comment: Same here, I need it, too.